# Constant current LED driver power to LED

Tags: pcb-design, led-driver

I am a little confused with the LEDs. These are the ones I have picked: [QBLP679-RGBCW][1]

They say 2 V red, 3.2 V green, 3.2 V green, 3.2 V white.

I need to run my PCB with 5 V input. Do I need to add resistors to drop the 5 V down?

Each colour should be limited to 20 mA with my 2.4 kΩ resistor.

Is there anything wrong with the way I have connected the LEDs to the 5 V?

I have removed my ground plane to make it easier to see my tracks.

If there is anything that looks wrong please help me.

Comment: Datasheet to U1?

Comment: Put all your signal connections on one layer and leave the other layer for a ground plane. There will be exceptions but, try to minimize the tracks on the ground plane as much as possible. What is U1? Please link its data sheet. Power supply decouplers are needed. What 2k4 resistor?

Comment: @Andyaka sorry its a TLC5947, Power supply decouplers on every LED?

Comment: With all channels driven, you'll be wasting around 1 W in the IC. If your vias go to a plane on the back side, you should be good. More decoupling capacitors may be needed, depending on how you drive them and feed the board.

Comment: @winny is there away to reduce the 1W that im wasting? also im just worried about the way i have connected the 5v to the LEDS with the via and connecting all pads

Comment: Step-down buck regulator to lower the input voltage, or a different IC with one buck per output.

Comment: I'm not making any sense of this. Do you know how diodes work? Forward voltages?

Answer (score 1):

It is the job of the [TLC5947](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5947.pdf) to worry about the current.  You've set the \$I_{REF}\$ resistor to 2.4k, which would give you a current of 20.5 mA to every LED connected to the TLC5947.  That also takes care of the voltage - LEDs are current driven devices, not voltage. In other words, if you put 20 mA through them  then the voltage give in the datasheet will appear across the LEDs.

The voltages in the LED datasheet are typical voltages for the LEDs when driven with 20 mA.  They are given as a range because all of the LEDs won't be identical and their behaviour changes with temperature.

---

C1 (100nF) in your circuit diagram is the decoupling capacitor mentioned in the comments and the datasheet.  You have it properly placed close to the power supply pins.

The electrolytic capacitors mentioned are for the 5V going to the LEDs.  The only guidance given is that the voltage for the LEDs should not vary be more than 5%.  You have fairly large tracks for the LED current, so that shouldn't be a problem.  You may want to include a pad for a 10µF capacitor.  Build it, try it.  If the 5V doesn't vary when changing brightness of all LEDs at once, then you don't have to install it.  If the 5V varies strongly when you switch all of the LEDs on or off, then install the 10µF capacitor and test it again.

Comment: So the 5v that flows to the leds does not mean the leds use the 5v passed to them?

Comment: The LEDs don't get 5V.  The constant current regulator in the TLC5947 takes the place of the resistor you would see in a simple LED, resistor, battery circuit.

Comment: The data sheet also says, Depending on the panel size, several electrolytic capacitors must be placed on the board, would i need them with this? if so i have no idea how many or even the size i would need

Comment: Thankyou for the help, with the 10µF capacitor your talking about, do you mean one for the full board or for every LED close to the pads?

Comment: One for the whole board.  You have really wide tracks for 5V to the LEDs. You also have a small board. That means the resistance and inductance of the 5V track should be low enough that only one big capacitor should be needed.

Comment: Thankyou so much, just one morer quick question, would the 10µF capacitor be best placed before or after my fuse?

Comment: After the fuse.  Electrolytic capacitors can go bad and fail short circuit.

Comment: The capacitor goes from fused 5V to ground.